Cant connect to local ubuntu server with ping or ssh, server can ping internet n router
Installed ubuntu server and openssh on old laptop installation went well. Settings good, all firewalls down, ssh active BUT still no machine can ping server n server can ping machines. Tried pinging ip4 with phones and tabs same result. Pings and ssh verbose usually timeout.
On running traceroute to devices no results just empty rows. All machines on same subnet and DNS.
Laptop connected to router with cable
Im out of ideas please help.

Make sure AP isolation isn't set in the router settings. I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure the AP isolation setting only applies to devices connected wirelessly so that might be the reason your wired device has access to the other devices but not visa versa.

No AP isolation setting on router n server pc cant ping locally only to internet

So even though it's connected with ethernet it should still ping or ssh regardless if it's wired or wireless, let's go over some basic troubleshooting and I would start with a reboot, restart, and reset for all devices.
1. Check SSH Service

Ensure that the SSH server (sshd) is running on your Ubuntu server:

Open a terminal on your Ubuntu server.
Run the following command to check if the SSH service is active:
sudo systemctl status ssh


If it's not active, start it with:
sudo systemctl start ssh


Make sure it's enabled to start on boot:
sudo systemctl enable ssh





2. Firewall Rules

Temporarily disable the firewall:
sudo ufw disable


Try connecting via SSH from your Windows PC again.

3. Network Configuration

Confirm that your PC and the Ubuntu server are on the same subnet and connected to the same router.
Check the IP addresses of both devices:

On your Windows PC:
ipconfig /all


On the Ubuntu server:
ip addr show


Ensure both devices have IP addresses in the same subnet (e.g., 192.168.1.x).



4. Hostname Issues

Check the hostname on your Ubuntu server:
hostnamectl


If incorrect, update it using:
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname your-desired-hostname


Restart the SSH service after changing the hostname:
sudo systemctl restart ssh



5. Traceroute

Run traceroute with the -T option (TCP traceroute):
traceroute -T 192.168.1.200



6. Check ARP Tables

Verify MAC addresses associated with IP addresses:

On the Ubuntu server:
arp -n


On your Windows PC:
arp -a





7. Router Configuration

Check router settings:

Ensure no MAC address filtering rules or port blocking rules affect SSH traffic.
Restart the router if necessary.



8. Physical Connection

Confirm laptop is physically connected to the router via cable.
Try a different cable or port on the router.

9. Reboot

Sometimes a reboot resolves networking issues.

10. Logs

Check system logs on the Ubuntu server:

/var/log/syslog
/var/log/auth.log




Followed 1-4 no changes, for 5 traceroute showed hostname n 3 different times, arp scan in server showed router with HWtype ether and an incomplete result for client pc, router and everything else fine. Have no idea where to start with system logs

Sorry for the late reply, hm this is interesting do you know if the router supports both bands 2.4 and 5ghz as well as the laptop? I mean it should since it can see it, are you behind a double NAT config by chance?

Try putting the router in DMZ mode, depends on the router where this setting would be but check that off and then try as well.
